# BigQuery - Join table on Array column

Tags: sql, arrays, join, google-bigquery

**Table 1**

| item | unit sold | item - 2 | unit sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1000 | y | 500 |

**Table 2**

| bundle items | items in bundle |
| --- | --- |
| a | ['x,y'] |
| b | ['x,y,z'] |

I need to join Table 1 & 2. If Item and item-2 match with items in bundle.

Desired result

| item | unit sold | item - 2 | unit sold | bundle items | items in bundle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1000 | y | 500 | a | [x,y] |
| x | 1000 | y | 500 | b | [x,y,z] |

I tried using unnest with no luck.

```
Left join (
    select b_sku, array_agg(c_sku) as children 
    from p
    group by p.b_sku
  ) y
ON i.sku = unnest(y.children)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that might work for you:

```
with table_a as (
  select 'x' as item, 1000 as unit_sold union all
  select 'y' as item, 500 as unit_sold union all
  select 'k' as item, 500 as unit_sold
),
table_b as (
  select 'x' as bundle_item, ['x', 'y'] as items_in_bundle union all
  select 'y' as bundle_item, ['x', 'y', 'z'] as items_in_bundle union all
  select 'k' as bundle_item, ['x', 'y', 'z'] as items_in_bundle
)
select * from table_a a 
left join  table_b b on a.item = b.bundle_item
where a.item in unnest(b.items_in_bundle)
```

As a result row with 'k' item wouldn't be joined because 'k' item is out of 'items_in_bundle' array.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below query.

> I need to join Table 1 & 2. *If Item and item-2 match with items in bundle.*

```sql
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT 'x' item, 1000 unit_sold, 'y' item_2, 500 unit_2_sold
),
table2 AS (
  SELECT 'a' bundle_items, ['x', 'y'] items_in_bundle UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', ['x', 'y', 'z'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', ['x', 'u', 'v']
)
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2  t2 
    ON t1.item IN UNNEST(t2.items_in_bundle) 
   AND t1.item_2 IN UNNEST(t2.items_in_bundle);
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. I was using '=' instead of 'IN'. Rookie mistake.